# What are benefits of using the @Deprecated notation on the interface only?

Tags: java, deprecated

For Java programming, what are some benefits of using the @Deprecated notation on and interface method but not on the class that implements it?

```
public interface Joe {

    @Deprecated
    public void doSomething();

    ...
}

public final class Joseph implements Joe {

    public void doSomething() {
       ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Why would you even depreciate the -only- method in an interface anyway? Just put in your release docs that "Interface 'Joe' is not used recommended to be used." or something.

Comment: There are other methods to the interface and class. Sorry Zack for the confusion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe it's a shortcoming in the Java Language itself and it is nonsense to specify a method in an interface as deprecated via an annotation and not have the method considered deprecated in the implementing class.

It would be better if the @deprecated-ness of the method were inherited.  Unfortunately, it seems Java does not support this.

Consider how tooling, such as an IDE, treats this situation: If the type of a variable is declared to be the interface, then @deprecated methods can be rendered with a strike through.  But if the type of a variable is declared to be the implementing class and the class signature does not include @deprecated, then the method will be rendered without a strike through.

The fundamental question is: what does it MEAN for a method to be deprecated in an interface but not in an implementing class (or in an extending interface)?  The only reasonable intention is for the method to be deprecated for everything below the interface in the class hierarchy.  But the language does not support that behavior.

Answer (score 12):

@Deprecated is documentation.  If people code to an interface you can mark certain aspects of that interface as deprecated.  That way people know not to use it.

The implementation class of the interface is a detail.  A method in that class happens to satisfy the interface but may not be deprecated on its own.  Deprecating that method may or may not be appropriate.

Creating a new class that implements an interface means you need to implement the deprecated methods.  They should probably work unless you know that the clients of the class don't use the deprecated methods.  For example, if you are creating an HTTP servlet container you need to implement the `HttpServletResponse.encodeUrl()` method even though it's deprecated in favour of `encodeURL()`.  That's because a user of your class may call that deprecated method.

Comment: Expanding on "Deprecating that [implementation] method may or may not be appropriate."  Specifically, it may be that the interface method doSomething is not appropriate for all implementations of Joe, but is appropriate for this particular implementation Joseph - thus the deprecation in the interface but not in this particular implementation.

Answer (score 6):

in my opinion it is **controversial**: *a deprecated method interface should not not be used regardless it's implementation* (please provide counterexamples if not)

Comment: I'd go further than controversial: I'd say it's questionable. I'd certainly ask for it to be justified in a code review.

Comment: Why not? That simply means that one method in the multi-method interface is planned to be removed in the future releases.

Comment: @Eugene: That may be true, but the example only showed one method. So, why even have that interface if it only has one method? :/ lol

Comment: @Eugene: Sometimes an interface is used as a marker and contains no methods, such as Serializable. If Serializable contained a method that was now deprecated it would still be a useful interface and Serializable objects should still implement that method if they expect to be compatible with any old clients.

Comment: @dfa, @CPerkins: A class should implement all the methods of its interfaces for compatibility with the clients that use them; if the Joe interface has any use besides that deprecated method then the deprecated method should be implemented.

Comment: a class **must** implement all the methods, no way :)

Comment: @dfa I meant implement the method properly, as opposed to a stub that's a no-op.

Comment: We use Rhino where Java methods will be called by versioned server side JavaScript codes. So I definitely must not remove methods from my Java interface because they may be called by old version of JavaScript. So I simple remove the method from my JavaScript code, and put a @Deprecated to the Java interface method.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to refactor the existing code with inappropriate methods in the interface and in the implementation, then we can use `@Deprecated` in the interface methods in favor of clean new methods temporarily for few releases. It may be ugly, just to keep the code backward compatible we can make use of it. This will show in the IDE and SONAR report that its a deprecated method and forcing the clients to use new methods.